# Remove row with zeros in large data set does not work

Tags: r

I have a large data set, namely Sachs which is freely available at the `gss` package. The data is so large with 7466 observations and 12 variables. I tried to remove all rows with at least one zero. That is, if one row contains zero, then remove this row over all the variables. For example,
if one variable contains zero value, then this row and the corresponding row of all other variables need to be removed. I tried all available methods and, I am failing. Here is one of my tries. I know that many similar questions are already there on this website, but I tried all of them but none of them work for me.

```
library(gss)
data <- data.frame(Sachs[,-12])
dat <- data[apply(data,1, function(x) all(data!= 0.0000000)),]
View(dat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove rows with contain at least one zero, you can use the following code:

```
library(gss)
data("Sachs")
Sachs[!apply(Sachs==0,1,any),]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain, the meaning of your code? It works.

Comment: @Dr.Alenezi, No problem! This will search for rows (1 in function means to check for rows) that have `any` value of 0 across all columns and select the rows that don't (!) meet that condition. So it will keep the rows with no zeros in them.

Answer (score 0):

Or using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gss)
data("Sachs")

Sachs |> filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ . == 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help, and giving me time to help me.